# What is the name of the chapter of charaka Samhita that deals with ideal food habits?

Tags: ayurveda, charaka-samhita

Charaka Samhita of the ancient books of Sanatana Dharma.

Consider the [following paragraph](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Charaka-samhita) from Britannica about Charaka Samhita

> Charaka divided the treatise into eight parts, or ashtanga sthanas:
> sutra, nidana, vimana, sarira, endriya, chikitsa, kalpa, and siddha;
> each part contained multiple chapters.

I want to know which one among these eight chapters contains details about the ideal diet for an individual.

What is the name of the chapter of charaka Samhita that deals with ideal food habits?

Answer (score 2):

In [sutra sthana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/charaka-samhita-english), chapter 27 - chapter 28 discuss about diets. Also chapter 26 should be given a reading.

Please also see this [Charak samhita - English](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/charaka-samhita-english/d/doc730008.html)