# How to prepare "meat juice" that has been mentioned in Charaka Samhita?

Tags: food, ayurveda

The following two excerpts from chapter **[27- Diet and Dietetics (Annapana-vidhi)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/charaka-samhita-english/d/doc627537.html)** of the Charaka Samhita mentions meat juice

#1: Meat-juice nourishes

> By its very nature, water moistens, salt liquefies, alkali digests,
> honey synthesizes, ghee causes unctuousness, milk gives life flesh
> causes roborance, **meat-juice nourishes**, wine causes senile
> degeneration Sidhu [sīdhu] wine causes emaciation, grape-wine
> stimulates digestion, treacle causes accumulation or morbid humors,
> curds cause edema, green Pinyaka [piṇyāka] causes depression.

#2: The qualities of Meat-juice

> For all creatures the meat-juice is most nourishing and cord[..??] and
> for those that are washed[?] convalescing, emaciated, deficient in
> semen and desirous of enhanced strength and complexion, meat-juice is
> to be regarded as nectar itself. Meat-juice administered as indicated
> is curative of most diseases. It should be regarded as promotive of
> voice, youth, intelligence, sense-faculties and longevity. If those
> given to constant exercise and indulgence in women and wine take
> meat-juice daily, they will never fall ill or become weak.

I found some related information about meat juice from [wisdomlib.org](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mamsarasa)

> Māṃsarasa (मांसरस):—Soup prepared with meat by adding 8 times of water
> & reducing it to 1 / 4th and seasoned with 3 pungents, ghee & jaggery

I am not sure whether the method given above has any scriptural basis. Does any scripture related to Ayurveda contain the method of preparing meat juice mentioned in the verses of Charaka Samhita?

Comment: Please mention the reason for the down-vote if possible.

Comment: I would be glad if you would accept my answer to your previous question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49333/what-is-the-name-of-the-chapter-of-charaka-samhita-that-deals-with-ideal-food-ha

Comment: @RaghavGoyal It may take some more time for my perfection. I generally accept once I understood it completely. But, I will surely accept.

Comment: Oh okay thanks :-)

Comment: Why you want to eat meat juice, it is very brutal to kill someone just because you want more nourishment

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Because I don't have such high knowledge to live without harming animals or plants.

Comment: @hanugm I think the intent was not to harm you, but I just wanted to say making *meat juice is brutal*

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Please read [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46034/does-any-scripture-other-than-mahabharata-say-that-plant-experiences-pain)